# Hide.rows script can't get permission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function ConditionalHideRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var condition = sheet.getRange(109,2,100,1).getValue();
  if (condition = " ") {
    sheet.hideRows(1);
  }    
}
```

I'm trying to hide rows that have " " in them within a certain range. However if I place the function in a cell it tells me "You do not have permission to call hideRows (line 7)."

I'm clueless how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as typo in

```
if (condition = " ") {
    sheet.hideRows(1)
   }
```

You probably mean

```
if (condition == " ") {
        sheet.hideRows(1)
       }
```

Please activate your function from the script page and answer on the "Request for Permission" window.

Comment: so i've been boiling on this for some time. apparently you cannot use this command in a custom function. i can only use commands in the same cell, wich obviously wont work for me as the cell already has a formula in it. any workarounds people know ?

Comment: Yes but you can execute that from the script page or create some custom button that will do this work.